# Object Passing from Angular to Controller showing Null Values for Parameters ? MVC

Tags: angularjs, object, model-view-controller, query-string

I am trying to pass object from AngularJS 1.x to controller my angular code is like,

```
 var searchCriteria =
                {
                    from: vm.From,
                    to: vm.To,
                    region: vm.SelectedRegion,
                    city: vm.SelectedCity,
                    buildingType: vm.selectedBuildType,
                    buildingid: vm.selectedHospitalID,
                    leaderId: vm.SelectedTeamLeader,
                    teamid: vm.SelectedTeam,
                    userId: vm.SelectedEvaluator,
                    trainerId: vm.SelectedTrainer,
                    status: vm.selectVisitStatus,
                }
```

Code to pass above object to controller ,

```
var controllerUrl = utilitiesService.getFullPath() + '/Survey/establishmentAllRecord/' + { searchCriteria: searchCriteria };
```

on controller side i am using this code,

```
public FileResult establishmentAllRecord(object searchCriteria)
{
}
```

On this controller in `object searchCreiteria` it shows all values null ??

any suggestions ?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do here. Why you are trying to add string and object.

Comment: i am actually passing object in query string

Comment: you probably should mention that your controller is actually an `asp.net` Controller (at least it looks like that), and you want to pass your clientside data to your serverside controller - and if thats the case - you should send your data to your server over the `$http` service , and for that purpose you should show us your _angularjs_ Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shold make POST request via, for example, `$http` service:

```
.controller('ctrl', ['$http', function($http){
    //your code...

    $http({
        url: utilitiesService.getFullPath() + '/Survey/establishmentAllRecord',
        method: "POST",
        data: searchCriteria
    });
}])



[HttpPost]
public FileResult establishmentAllRecord(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{
}
```

Comment: It is not sending request to controller getting error : $http is not defined

Comment: I guess this should work, You need to inject '$http' in your controller before using it.

Comment: @Doc, look at extended answer.

Comment: @Hari how to do it?

Comment: @Guys i dont want to do it using service. I want to do it from angular to to direct controller

Comment: I have edited @Slava Utesinov's answers to inject $http